# Not able to commit force.com project to Bitbucket due to specific error

Tags: force.com, versioning, git

I have added a **force.com project to eclipse**, but when i am trying to **push/commit the entire project to bitbucket master** branch it's giving me the following specific error -

Following is the project in eclipse - [image]

**Then trying to commit the code in Bitbucket using -**

**Right Click on Project -> Team -> Commit**, Its giving me the following error -[image] -

**Following is the Error -**

[image]

Comment: Are you able to commit to git using your CLI instead of an eclipse plugin?

Comment: I need to make this from eclipse, can you please elaborate the step so that i can try to commit from CLI. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Atlassian has some documentation available: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/basic-git-commands-776639767.html